# Dynamic Data Display more than one lines in one chart for WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data-display

I am receiving some data and I would like to represent it in a graph view using dynamic data display. All what I could do until now is create one line in the chart which is working fine. Now I would like to create more detailed charts which is representing changes of more than one variable in the time.

How I can implement that? Thanks

Comment: Try Oxyplot http://www.oxyplot.org/

Comment: I am already using Dynamic Data Display, and I am very happy with one diagram which I already have, I would like the same type, just show more information... Anyway thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Please look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984082/how-to-add-mutiple-graph-in-one-x-y-plane-in-wpf-using-dynamicdatadisplay/40992126#40992126)